# React updating state for child components

Tags: reactjs

My app is structured as follows:

```
<App>
    <SelectItems/>
    <Tabs>
        <Tab> <Window1> </Tab>
        <Tab> <Window2> </Tab>
    </Tabs>
</App>
```

The `App` has a state element called `allItems`, and `SelectItems` is used to narrow this down to `App.state.selectedItems`. The tabs work in a way that only one of the tabs shows at a given time, it's a component from `React-Bootstrap`.

The `Window1` and `Window2` display data that depend on the `selectedItems`, the data (let's call it `data1` and `data2`) is obtained via a computationally intensive api call. Here's the problem. The cleanest way to do this while thinking in React is to "pull the state up", so that `data1` and `data2` are updated from `App` whenever the `selectedItems` change, and the data is then stored in the state of `App` and passed down to the tabs. This however is inefficient, because only one `Window` is showing at a given time, so I'm wasting time updating data that I'm never showing. In my actual app I've got many tabs, so it's a real problem.

What's a way of fixing this? I want the `Window`s to update whenever the `App.state.selection` changes, and I looked at `static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state)` but it looks like (but I'm not sure) that this function won't work because the state updating would be asynchronous, as it requires an API call.

Are there general strategies one can use in this situation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, the first one is the one most people would recommend (because it is a popular option) and that is to use [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) to manage your application state.

Redux will allow you to keep all your data in a separate "store". Then from your components you can connect to the store and access the data which is relevant to them. Those components should only update when the data they are interested in is changed, any other changes to the store will be ignored.
There are a lot of good tutorials on using Redux and React together which you can find online - apparently the ones on egghead are pretty good, you can maybe try [this one](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) to get started.

Your other option might be to use a `PureComponent` so that you can limit when your component will re-render to only when it's props or state change rather than if the parent re-renders. You can read about this [here](https://60devs.com/pure-component-in-react.html). It's actually similar to the previous solution are the connect function provided by the `react-redux` library to connect to the Redux store wraps your component in a PureComponent.

Comment: The approach I'm using right now is to run the API calls on mount inside `Window1` and `Window2`, and render the windows as follows: `<Window1 key = {this.getUniqueHashFromSelectedData() }/>`, this ensures that the components re-mount and thus refresh their data, but it also very much seems like a hack.

Comment: I think the possibilities are too many, you have to narrow down what you want.
I believe the react key magic can actually be justified, i've used it a couple times, but I'm not sure it's good for in this case.
One thing you can do is that you pass a prop to the tabs that tells them if they are rendered currently. If they are not active, you simply prevent the render with shouldComponentUpdate.